# .load doesn't work with IE and Opera

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I've got this code:

```
function openFile(_title, file, id, _height, _width)
{
    $.fx.speeds._default = 500;
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if (_height == '')
            _height = 250;

        if (_width == '')
            _width = 500;

        var dialogOpts = {
            title: _title,
            modal: true,
            height: _height,
            width: _width,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            show: "puff",
            hide: "puff"
        };

        $("#dialog").dialog(dialogOpts);

        $("#dialog").load(file, [], function(){ $("#dialog").dialog("open"); });
    });
}
```

it works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but neither in Opera nor IE. The dialog box pops up, but without content in it. It just shows the title.

I tried changing the last line to

```
$.get(file, function(result) {
    $('#dialog').append(result);
});
```

and

```
$("#dialog").load(file);
```

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$("#dialog").load(file, [], function(){ $("#dialog").dialog("open"); });` to:

```
$("#dialog").load(file, [], function(response, status, xhr){
    if(status!="error")
        $("#dialog").dialog(); 
});
```

[The default behavior](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) of the dialog box is to open.

Comment: @mindaugas It doesn't pop-up or it's still empty? If it doesn't pop-up your ajax call could have failed. That's what `status!="error"` does. Before when it was empty it was probably because the `.load` was failing but you were still opening the dialog. Try putting in an alert to see what the `status` is.

Comment: the dialog box does pop up, but it's still empty.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with `.load()` before, so now I use `.get()` instead.

Quick example:

```
 $.get(url,function(data){  $("#dialog").html(data);  });
```

Comment: What do your `<script>` tags look like?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mctop.lt/user/themes/default/js/custom.js"></script> you can see whole source in mctop.lt

Comment: Yea, well I get some errors when I goto this site, `line 31: (function() )(); - syntax error`, should be `function(){};`, which is possibly breaking your code.